# How do I delete record in multiple table in microsoft access

Tags: ms-access, select, highlight, sql-delete

How do I delete records from multiple table that is selected in the subform, which appear on the textbox below when selected. The "Remove Software" Button is suppose to delete it, is created with the wizard but is of no use.

[image]

Comment: Can you give more details please, how many tables is the data present in?

Comment: It comes from 4 different table in total.

Comment: this is the query statement on the combobox that show the records in the subform.


SELECT Employee.EmpName, Employee.EmpCode, Employee.CompanyID, Employee.DeptID, Computer.ComputerName, Software.ProductName
FROM Software INNER JOIN ((Computer INNER JOIN Employee ON Computer.ComputerID = Employee.ComputerID) INNER JOIN Application ON Computer.ComputerName = Application.[ComputerID]) ON Software.ID = Application.SoftwareID
WHERE (((Application.SoftwareID)=[Forms]![Software_LicenseTracking]![CbProductName]));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I like this table structure, it appears from the screenshot and SQL that **Application.SoftwareID** and **Software.ProductName** are the same so not sure why you need both tables.

However you only need delete from **Application** where the **ComputerID** is the one selected, I'm not sure if the Computer Name field on the form is this but if so then:

```
DELETE FROM Application WHERE ComputerID = [Forms]![Software_LicenseTracking]![ComputerName]
```

If not then you could expose the relevant computerID field via a hidden textbox and use that.

Comment: thx it work idealy, i get what u mean. Unfortunately i inherited this work from the previous guys before me who left it half done. Im acutally thinking of redesigning it too. Is too tedious to work with something thats half done.